# Python2.7 import pyautogui xlib error

Tags: python

I have a problem, when I try import `pyautogui` I will get this error msg.

> `Xlib.xauth`: warning, failed to parse part of `xauthority` file
>   (`/home/John/.Xauthority`), aborting all further parsing

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to python-xlib=0.14+20091101-1ubuntu2 may help: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-xlib/+bug/1522107

Comment: (The error can be reproduced in the python command line by the commands "from Xlib import xauth" and "xauth.Xauthority()".)