# Python 3 import pynput xlib warning

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem, when I try import pynput I will get this warning msg.

`Xlib.xauth: warning, failed to parse part of xauthority file (/home/John/.Xauthority), aborting all further parsing`

It's very annoying, please help me.
[python2 solution, but I can't use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381035/python2-7-import-pyautogui-xlib-error/37634194#37634194)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?